# Wordpress Widget Textarea Auto Paragraph

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, textarea, paragraph

I am in the works of throwing together what I believe to be a fairly simple widget for a client site, but being my second Widget ever I still have quite a bit of a learning curve to overcome.

### The Story

In this particular project I have attempted to create some textarea inputs to output into some simple paragraph tags. But I kinda tackled it as logically as I could but I am sure it is pretty gross code as I am not a PHP expert by even the leanest standards.

### The Issue

My issue is that I wish to have my textarea's output with auto paragraphing. Such as the default text widget wordpress provides when the checkbox is checked. Also maybe just have a look over at how I even created the textarea's. I am sure there is a better practice then what I put together.

#### Textarea Sample

```
<p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'admitted' ); ?>"><?php _e('Admitted to Practice', 'framework') ?></label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'admitted' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'admitted' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'admitted' ); ?>" /><?php echo $instance['admitted']; ?></textarea>
    </p>
```

I don't know if maybe putting tinymce on them would help solve this or not (not that I know how to do that) But I am wide open to suggestions.

Take a look at the full code here.
[Dropbox Zip of Widget](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iies0yt5efg2sq6/attorney_information.zip)

Comment: Which function is your textarea sample? Is it your form function or your widget function?

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused by your question. This sample is the textarea form to be displayed inside of the widget.

Comment: Within your widget class you should have four functions, __construct, update, form and widget.  If you could post your full widget code here that would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the code below.

```
<p><strong>Admitted to Practice:</strong><br/><?php echo wpautop($this->admitted_practice); ?></p>
```

Thank you Calle for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can easily look at how the default widgets are built, right? Just go to wp-includes/default-widgets.php

If I understand your issue correctly you are looking for this piece of code in the class WP_Widget_Text in that file,

```
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
                <div class="textwidget"><?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?></div>
```

As you can see, it is the wpautop function that does the trick.

I think the way you created your form is fine. If you want to learn best practices, again, Wordpress source code is useful.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I dug into that last night. The default text widget is built slightly differently, But I was able to there.